# ReportServerPowerBI - dbo.ExecutionLogStorage - columns meaning

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, power-bi-report-server

I want to build some basic monitoring/dashboard for reports (paginated/PBI).

I am reading table `dbo.ExecutionLogStorage`, but I don´t know some values in the columns.

Column `ReportAction` --> I know this below -->
`CASE(ReportAction) WHEN 1 THEN 'Render' WHEN 2 THEN 'BookmarkNavigation' WHEN 3 THEN 'DocumentMapNavigation' WHEN 4 THEN 'DrillThrough' WHEN 5 THEN 'FindString' WHEN 6 THEN 'GetDocumentMap' WHEN 7 THEN 'Toggle' WHEN 8 THEN 'Sort' WHEN 9 THEN 'Execute' ELSE 'Unknown' END AS ItemAction,`

And What numbers from 10 to 19?

I didn´t found any documentation. Do you have some documentation or something else?

Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

I think anything after 9 is PowerBI specific as I as only have actions up to 9 (as I don't use PowerBI Reports only classic SSRS).

I'm running SQL Server 2016 but I found this in the `dbo.ExecutionLog3` view. You could script out that view and see if the other codes are listed, or maybe you can use this view directly for your query.

```
CASE(ReportAction)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Render'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'BookmarkNavigation'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'DocumentMapNavigation'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'DrillThrough'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'FindString'
    WHEN 6 THEN 'GetDocumentMap'
    WHEN 7 THEN 'Toggle'
    WHEN 8 THEN 'Sort'
    WHEN 9 THEN 'Execute'
    WHEN 10 THEN 'RenderEdit'
    WHEN 11 THEN 'ExecuteDataShapeQuery'
    WHEN 12 THEN 'RenderMobileReport'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS ItemAction
```

Comment: Thank you. So I want to find some documentation for these views.